# WiFi triangulation on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, wifi, triangulation

Lets say you have a zoo and you want to create an app which shows you details on each animal whenever you are next to the cage. (just for the sake of this question ... GPS signals are not an option)

If there was a WiFi router next to each cage, are there any methods the iPhone app can use to work out that the phone is nearby? I guess this is WiFi triangulation.

Or are there other methods to do this kind of geolocation without GPS?

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone can detect the intensity of the signal.. So it may be enough having a router inside each cage, with some calculated emission power.

However, if it gets crowded, mapping the routers and comparing intensities of different routers might work.

Nice idea =)

--hiring a guide might also do the job :D

Comment: I guess you could find out what the MAC address of the nearest router is, compare it to a map, and find a location that way.

Comment: Indeed. The app containing the map could be loaded on the phone at the entrance. Would be nice.

Comment: @Anne But does the phone have an Bluetooth-intensity-meter so it can approximate the distance?

Comment: Andre, how would you detect the intensity of the WiFi signals?

Answer (score 1):

The iPod touch actually uses this kind of triangulation to get the iPod's location, but it requires a lot of data mining and is a lot less precise than GPS.

You could try it though, in a smaller area (like a zoo) it imagine it would be possible: calculate the intensity of the signal from every router and estimate the distance from three of them according to signal strength.

Another option in this specific case would be to offer an app to scan a bar code at every cage and display the animal info.